# Make If statement with OR || and && checks

Tags: if-statement, prolog

How may I make something like this in prolog:

```
if(A > -1 && A > 0){
   //DoSomething
}
else{
   //DoAnotherThing
}
```

Tried this:

```
positive([], []). %Tudo Vazio
positive([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :- H1 > -1, H1 > 0 ->  H2 = H1, positivos(T1, T2).
```

Comment: `if(A > -1 && A > 0)` is equivalent to `if(A > 0)`, just to simplify things. And you said you "Tried this:...", so what happened? Be mindful of operator precedence. Compare the precedence of `->` versus `,`. Prolog isn't like C. If you have, `p :- p1, p2, ..., pn` it means, *`p` is true if `p1` is true, and `p2` is true, and...* for some instantiation of the variables. You don't really need the `->`.

Comment: You really need to show what you expect to get and what you get instead. This includes first getting rid of any compiler errors and warning.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Prolog is a Logical Programming language and not like C or equivalents.

Prolog will 'succeed' or 'fail' to check anything you throw at it.
So if you'd want to check if A is positive (which I think you want to do) you can simply write:

```
positive(A) :- A > 0.
```

If you want to check if all numbers in a list are positive then you'd recurse through a list checking all it's members with the previous predicate like:

```
positive([]).
positive([H|T]) :-
     positive(H),
     positive(T).
```

An 'if/then' in Prolog could be written with `;` which is Prolog for `or`.

```
positive(A) :-
    ( 
        A > 0,  print('A is positive')
        ; 
        A < 0,  print('A is negative')
        ; 
        A == 0, print('A is zero')
    ).
```

Test it by asking prolog `positive(1)` or `positive(-1)`.

Comment: I strongly recommend you reformat the last example so that `;` always occurs *in front* of the line, not at the end. This is because `;` looks almost the same as `,`

Comment: I also recommend to add parentheses, and to reflect the semantic nesting in the syntactic indenting.

Comment: Please see line ~100 of [https://github.com/mndrix/tp/blob/master/prolog/patch.pl](https://github.com/mndrix/tp/blob/master/prolog/patch.pl) for a sensible way to indent a disjunction. In fact, I recommend a bit more indent width than in this example. The main point is to place `;` *in front* of the lines, instead of, as you are now again doing, at the end. It is way too easy to mistake `;` for `,` if you place both at the end.